# Error al importar un excel con un JTable, me da error en el archivo

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi, java-import

Para hacerlo utilicé apache poi y netbeans, aún así no importa lo que haga, parece que no me acepta el archivo, incluso si le pongo el "XLS" en el nombre directo o si le pongo "XSLS". Ya no se que hacer, he visto demasiados tutoriales y ninguno parece reparar el error del importe.

```
*/
package controles;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import Visuals.visualtabla;
import Model.ExcelModel;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

/**
 *
 * @author gala_
 */
public class TableControls implements ActionListener{
    ExcelModel modeloE = new ExcelModel();
    visualtabla vistaE = new visualtabla();
    JFileChooser selecArchivo = new JFileChooser();
    File archivo;
    int contAccion=0;

public TableControls(visualtabla vistaE, ExcelModel modeloE){  
    this.vistaE = vistaE;
    this.modeloE= modeloE;
    this.vistaE.botonImport.addActionListener(this);
}  

public void AgregarFiltro(){
    selecArchivo.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel (*.xls)", "xls"));
    selecArchivo.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel (*.xlsx)", "xlsx"));
}
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        contAccion++;
        if(contAccion==1)AgregarFiltro();
        
        if(e.getSource()== vistaE.botonImport){
          if(selecArchivo.showDialog(null, "Seleccionar archivo")==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
              archivo=selecArchivo.getSelectedFile();
              if(archivo.getName().endsWith("xls") || archivo.getName().endsWith("xlsx")){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                            modeloE.Importar(archivo, vistaE.datosTabla) + "\n Formato ."+ archivo.getName().substring(archivo.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1), 
                            "IMPORTAR EXCEL", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                  }else{
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Elija un formato válido.");
              }
          }  
        }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque pedir ayuda urgente es descortés y hasta grosero](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152) :)

Comment: El código solo muestra la ventana para buscar el archivo, no hace nada más. Esa ventana no te aparece?

Comment: Prueba con `new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel (*.xls,*.xlsx)", "xls","xlsx")`